# How can I find an installed drivers version in Python under Windows?

Tags: python-2.7, driver, wmi

I am trying to call a python [module] method to find the version of a newly installed driver on a Windows computer. Tried with WMI_SystemDriver but it does not provide the version, only other fields not needed by me at this time.Is there a way to see something like:

Question also posted on a Google group - not answered

version x.y.z.t

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is going to sound different but I know the powershell command will get you the driver version.

strCommand = r"powershell.exe ""Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver | select devicename, driverversion | ConvertTo-CSV"""

Then you can parse each line in your output.  Each line is csv delimited so you have the Driver Name, and the Driver Version.  I wrote a quick demo but since I am still a bit new here my code did not look right.  But that is my suggestion.

Comment: I have to do this procedure on many platforms that don't come with powershell installed so it would be great for me to find a method that does not require installing it on each and every machine.

Comment: i used the above but i can't see the driverversion because the drivers i'm looking for are unsigned. Any idea?